# I wanted to allow outgoing DNS traffic while OUTPUT is on DROP

Tags: networking, bash, dns, iptables, firewall

I currently have a dns server running on my pi , and I am using that as my dns
I wanted to ping google.ca while my output chain / input being on drop
here are my firewall rules would love to hear some feedback on how to fix this still cant ping google.ca

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
#ssh
#http traffic
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo  -j ACCEPT
#loopback
#outgoing dns
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
#incoming dns 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Can you include the full current iptables rules?  `sudo iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers` and add it as an edit to the question?

Comment: I do flush the iptables in the script

Comment: Please do as @ThomasWard asked. We need to see your default policies and the overall context. If you want to allow ping, then you need rules to do so if your default policy is DROP.

Comment: There's also a few things that I would add anyways, such as a state matching on RELATED,ESTABLISHED in INPUT and OUTPUT and allow it, that way you don't have to explicitly allow all connections to a port and instead only permit the traffic that's related to the NEW traffic you're establishing outboud.  BUt yes, we still want to see the current layout *after* your script runs.